# error: cannot find php_pdo_driver.h while installing pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to load pdo_mysql extension to php inorder to install Megento in my VPS (runs CentOS).
Then I searched the PHP.ini file for something like "extension=pdo.so ". But I was unable to find such a line in my ini file. Then I tried to install pdo_mysql using "pecl install" . But the installation exits by displaying this error ,

```
checking for PDO includes... checking for PDO includes...
configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/PDO_MYSQL/configure' failed
```

My [phpinfo](http://megatrontech.com/phpinfo.php) . Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build PHP with PDO support.

http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO

"Do not use this, as PDO has been moved into core (the php source) so this pecl extension is dead."

Answer (score 1):

Current PHP comes with PDO extension in its core, but **you still need to add support for each database engine you need to connect to**.

I had this problem with symfony2 complaning about the lack of pdo_pgsql driver. I looked everywhere on the web and basically concluded that I had to do (in ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo pecl install pdo_pgsql
```

But that will fail, basically for the same reason as it failed you (in my case it said `configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.`)

then, by accident, I found out that you need to install the packages as

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

and that will add pdo_pgsql and pdo_mysql to your PDO driver.

In centOS, it should be

```
sudo yum install php-pgsql
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

Comment: I'm having the same error when trying to compile a PDO Dblib driver in Mac Os... What should i do ?

Comment: @delphirules the only useful mention I could find was this one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1539743