# PDO DBLIB Driver for MS SQL Server : Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, homebrew

I'm following the tutorial on the link below to compile PDO's DBLIB driver in my Mac Os Mojave.

https://github.com/BellevueCollege/public-docs/blob/master/PHP/configure-mssql-pdodblib-mac.md

Problem is, when i run the code below :

```
$ cd php-7.2.9/ext/pdo_dblib
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/
$ make
$ sudo cp modules/pdo_dblib.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
```

Specifically on this command :

```
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/
```

I get this error :

```
configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.
```

Any ideas please ? I've been trying for the last 2 hours : /

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 days struggling with this issue, i could find what was wrong.

Because i installed another PHP version in my machine (7.2.9), is was installed not in the default MacOS Mojave folder /usr/bin/php, but instead on `/usr/local/php5-7.2.9-20180821-074958`. Because of this, on the command below i'd need to change from :

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/
```

To

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5-7.2.9-20180821-074958/bin/php-config --with-mssql=/usr/local/
```

After that i could compile the extesion properly.

Answer (score 3):

actually PDO is included on PHP core. You must install the PHP and MySQL bundled packages.

And follow the following steps to install `dblib`
[PDO DBLIB Driver for MS SQL Server : Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550255/installing-extensions-to-the-bundled-php-in-os-x)

Check out this solution also: 
[error: cannot find php_pdo_driver.h while installing pdo_mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054826/error-cannot-find-php-pdo-driver-h-while-installing-pdo-mysql)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying to install DBLIB, not My SQL.

Comment: I don't understand, the answer continues with a reference to sybase ? "sudo apt-get install php5-sybase"

Comment: Moreover, when i run 'sudo apt-get install php5-sybase' , i get 'sudo: apt-get: command not found'

Comment: did you follow this step `From the directory of your PHP download, you'll move to the PDO_DBLIB extensions folder of PHP, build the pdo_dblib.so file, then copy it to the PHP extensions folder.`

Comment: and have completed all these steps as well [Get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

Comment: The problem is specifically when i try to build the pdo_dblib.so file, i get this 'configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.' error when running the command './configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/